# What do these sentences mean? Please translate or paraphrase

Tags: translation

"There is in the works of Emerson an underlying tone of quiet appreciation."
"There is stashed below the frigid depths of the arctic a magnificent treasure that no one has ever been able to recover."

What do these two sentences mean??

Comment: It  is  only  one  sentence.

Comment: If we reverse the inversion, will they make sense to you? "There is an underlying tone of quiet appreciation in the works of Emerson" / "There is a magnificent treasure that no one has ever been able to recover stashed below the frigid depths of the artic".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There  is  stored below in the  coldest  depths  of the  arctic ocean  a  magnificent wealth that  none  has  been  able  to  recover  till now.

There  might  be  metaphorical meaning  in the  sentence.Unless  we  read  the essay we  can not  tell exactly  what it  is. Anyhow, he  is  talking about the  hidden treasure may  be  referring  to  man. I am not sure unless  I  read the  text.

Answer (score 0):

A magnificent treasure - that no one has ever been able to recover - is stashed in the frigid depths of the arctic.